# Java FX Scaled Canvas

Tags: canvas, javafx, scale

I am using JavaFX and would like to use a Canvas of fixed pixel size, which can be scaled to fill a window and will grow when the window is resized.

I'm using SceneBuilder for my FXML.

*Update 30-MAY-2015. I realise I have specified the problem poorly. What I am after is that the Canvas component is NOT resized; that is the internal raster dimensions remain unchanged, but rather a scaling and transformation is applied to it so that it fills the available space.*

My starting point is the following:

FXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.canvas.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="scalingcanvas.FXMLDocumentController">
   <center>
      <AnchorPane BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <Canvas fx:id="canvas" height="200.0" width="200.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
   </center>
   <top>
      <Label text="top" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
   </top>
   <bottom>
      <Label text="bottom" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
   </bottom>
   <left>
      <Label text="left" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
   </left>
   <right>
      <Label text="right" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
   </right>
</BorderPane>
```

Java FX controller:

```
package scalingcanvas;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;

public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Canvas canvas;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        System.out.printf("hi\n");
        GraphicsContext g2d = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
        double w = canvas.getWidth();
        double h = canvas.getHeight();
        g2d.setFill(Color.ALICEBLUE);
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
        g2d.setStroke(Color.BLUE);
        g2d.strokeOval(0, 0, w, h);
        g2d.strokeLine(0, 0, w, h);
        g2d.strokeLine(0, h, w, 0);
    }    
}
```

Java main application:

```
package scalingcanvas;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ScalePanel extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

I understand why the existing code does not scale the Canvas when the window is grown, but what do I need to add to achieve this?

Also I need the scaled Canvas to maintain its underlying aspect ratio (as specified by its pixel width and height) and also remain centred in the enclosing node whet the enclosing node's aspect ratio is not the same as that of the Canvas.

Any help gratefully appreciated.

Comment: The Ensemble 8 sample application from Oracle contains an [example for a resizable canvas](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8u40/rt/file/eb264cdc5828/apps/samples/Ensemble8/src/samples/java/ensemble/samples/graphics2d/canvas/SanFranciscoFireworks.java#l112).

Answer (score 2):

Based on code I found [here](http://gillius.org/blog/2013/02/javafx-window-scaling-on-resize.html) I finally arrived at this solution:

```
/*
 * Based on http://gillius.org/blog/2013/02/javafx-window-scaling-on-resize.html
 */
package dsfxcontrols;

import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;

/**
 * A StackPane that <i>scales</i> its contents to fit (preserving aspect ratio),
 * or fill (scaling independently in X and Y) the available area.
 * <p>
 * Note <code>AutoScalingStackPane</code> applies to the contents a scaling
 * transformation rather than attempting to resize the contents.
 * <p>
 * If the contents is a Canvas with pixel dimension 50 by 50, after scaling the
 * Canvas still will have 50 by 50 pixels and the appearance may be pixelated
 * (this might be desired if the application is interfacing a camera and the
 * Canvas needs to match in size the camera's CCD size).
 * <p>
 * If the content contains FX Controls then these get magnified rather than
 * resized, that is all text and graphics are scaled (this might be desired for
 * Point of Sale full screen applications)
 * <p>
 * <h3>Known Limitations</h3>
 * Rescaling occurs only when the AutoScalingStackPane is resized, it does not
 * occur automatically if and when the content changes size.
 *
 *
 * @author michaelellis
 */
public class AutoScalingStackPane extends StackPane {

    /**
     * Force scale transformation to be recomputed based on the size of this
     * <code>AutoScalingStackPane</code> and the size of the contents.
     */
    public void rescale() {
        if (!getChildren().isEmpty()) {
            getChildren().forEach((c) -> {
                double xScale = getWidth() / c.getBoundsInLocal().getWidth();
                double yScale = getHeight() / c.getBoundsInLocal().getHeight();
                if (autoScale.get() == AutoScale.FILL) {
                    c.setScaleX(xScale);
                    c.setScaleY(yScale);
                } else if (autoScale.get() == AutoScale.FIT) {
                    double scale = Math.min(xScale, yScale);
                    c.setScaleX(scale);
                    c.setScaleY(scale);
                } else {
                    c.setScaleX(1d);
                    c.setScaleY(1d);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private void init() {
        widthProperty().addListener((b, o, n) -> rescale());
        heightProperty().addListener((b, o, n) -> rescale());
    }

    /**
     * No argument constructor required for Externalizable (need this to work
     * with SceneBuilder).
     */
    public AutoScalingStackPane() {
        super();
        init();
    }

    /**
     * Convenience constructor that takes a content Node.
     *
     * @param content
     */
    public AutoScalingStackPane(Node content) {
        super(content);
        init();
    }

    /**
     * AutoScale scaling options:
     * {@link AutoScale#NONE}, {@link AutoScale#FILL}, {@link AutoScale#FIT}
     */
    public enum AutoScale {

        /**
         * No scaling - revert to behaviour of <code>StackPane</code>.
         */
        NONE,
        /**
         * Independently scaling in x and y so content fills whole region.
         */
        FILL,
        /**
         * Scale preserving content aspect ratio and center in available space.
         */
        FIT
    }

    // AutoScale Property
    private ObjectProperty<AutoScale> autoScale = new SimpleObjectProperty<AutoScale>(this, "autoScale",
            AutoScale.FIT);

    /**
     * AutoScalingStackPane scaling property
     *
     * @return AutoScalingStackPane scaling property
     * @see AutoScale
     */
    public ObjectProperty<AutoScale> autoScaleProperty() {
        return autoScale;
    }

    /**
     * Get AutoScale option
     *
     * @return the AutoScale option
     * @see AutoScale
     */
    public AutoScale getAutoScale() {
        return autoScale.getValue();
    }

    /**
     * Set the AutoScale option
     *
     * @param newAutoScale
     * @see AutoScale
     *
     */
    public void setAutoScale(AutoScale newAutoScale) {
        autoScale.setValue(newAutoScale);
    }
}
```

The AutoScalingStackPane applies a scaling transform to scale its contents to fill or fit (aspect ratio preserved) to the StackPane size. I've added an AutoScale property that allows you to choose the scaling option (NONE, FIT, SCALE).

If you compile into a Jar it can be used (and tested) with SceneBuilder. Here is my fxml that uses it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.web.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import dsfxcontrols.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import scalingcanvas.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?language javascript?>

<BorderPane fx:id="root" prefHeight="324.0" prefWidth="318.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">

    <top>
        <Label text="top" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
    </top>
    <bottom>
        <Label fx:id="bottom" text="bottom" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
    </bottom>
    <left>
        <Label text="left" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
    </left>
    <right>
        <Label text="right" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
    </right>
    <center>
        <AutoScalingStackPane minHeight="20.0" minWidth="20.0" style="-fx-border-color: blue; -fx-background-color: aliceblue;" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">

            <children>
                <Group>
                    <children>
                        <Circle fill="#c891c9b2" radius="100.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" />
                        <Circle fill="#ff781f62" layoutX="73.0" layoutY="111.0" radius="79.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" />
                        <Rectangle arcHeight="5.0" arcWidth="5.0" fill="DODGERBLUE" height="129.0" layoutX="-22.0" layoutY="-19.0" opacity="0.24" stroke="#f80000" strokeType="INSIDE" strokeWidth="3.0" width="141.0" />
                        <Button layoutX="-86.0" layoutY="150.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="bottom.setText(Date());timeLabel.setText(Date());" text="Hello" />
                  <Label fx:id="timeLabel" alignment="CENTER" layoutX="-86.0" layoutY="-70.0" text="Label" textAlignment="CENTER">
                     <font>
                        <Font name="Brush Script MT Italic" size="12.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
                    </children>
                </Group>
            </children>
        </AutoScalingStackPane>
    </center>
</BorderPane>
```

Since this only required so little code, I wonder if StackPane could include this scaling functionality directly. It seems it could be useful and there would be hardly any API changes (just the inclusion of the extra AutoScale property)